# Ionic modal height fitting content

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, modalviewcontroller

Setting ionic modal height to auto/fit-content not working.

I'm trying to make an ionic modal on angular, have its setted according to its content. Currently i need to create the modals by a modalController, calling a custom component. If i just create them and don't pass any styles, the modal opens on the correct breakpoint i specify, however, if i swipe it to the top, it then fills the whole screen, but i want it to occupy only the height needed to fit its content. I already tried something like:

```
ion-modal {
 --height: auto;
}
```

or

```
ion-modal {
 --height: fit-content;
}
```

and some other stuff, like wrapping the modal component in ion-content, or div class="inner-content". But then the height gets kinda glitchy, and the content overflows to the bottom of the screen, instead of showing it all. Any ideas on the most recent ionic version?

```
public async startNewProject() {
    const modal = await this.modalController.create({
      component: NewProjectTypeComponent,
      breakpoints: [0, .50],
      initialBreakpoint: .50,
      cssClass: 'custom-border-radius-modal',
      handle: false,

    })
    modal.present();
  }

<ion-grid>
  <div class="top-bar"></div>
  <ion-row class="title-row">
    <ion-label class="main-title">Qual o tipo de projeto?</ion-label>
  </ion-row>
  <ion-row class="row">
    <ion-item (click)="openProjectTitleModal()">
        <ion-icon src="../../../../assets/icon/home-filled-icon.svg"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Residêncial</ion-label>
      <ion-icon class="arrow-right" slot="end" src="../../../../assets/icon/arrow-right.svg"></ion-icon>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-row>
  <ion-row class="row">
    <ion-item (click)="openProjectTitleModal()">
      <ion-icon src="../../../../assets/icon/industry-icon.svg"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Industrial</ion-label>
      <ion-icon class="arrow-right" slot="end" src="../../../../assets/icon/arrow-right.svg"></ion-icon>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-row>
  <ion-row class="row">
    <ion-item (click)="openProjectTitleModal()">
      <ion-icon src="../../../../assets/icon/suitcase-icon.svg"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Escritório</ion-label>
      <ion-icon class="arrow-right" slot="end" src="../../../../assets/icon/arrow-right.svg"></ion-icon>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

So you are using the bottomsheet modal by passing the in the `breakpoints: [0, .50], initialBreakpoint: .50,`

In your case what you described, it's the wrong type of modal. You need to use a regular modal by removing those 2 props and then you will get the correct modal height/width.